# Opening same .Net Project in many computers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, project-management, project

I am working on a project and my system is connected to the server running windows server 2008 r2.

We are 4 people working on the same project on different machine.

Now every one code the project from the own system stored locally

But i want all of us to be working on the same project located at one placed.

So that every one's work is synchronised..

Currently We are using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

But we dont have Team Server

Comment: You want "version control". There are several superb free ones. Look (for example) at Subversion, Mercurial or Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not only want source control, you ***need*** source control. I suggest you also start reading the Joel test:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

And I would recomend the "The Pragmatic Programmer" to you:

http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer

Comment: @David: agreed, see my edit. Interesting that beginners have the bucks for using VS 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using source control of some sort.  There are many free products to choose from, and some low-cost hosted ones.

Personally, prefer SVN (Subversion) but there are tons of alternatives.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_hosting_facilities

SourceForge and Google Code appear to be popular hosting providers.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for SubVersion (SVN) it integrates nice with Visual Studio if you use [VisualSVN](http://www.google.no/aclk?sa=l&ai=Cmbk-33THTsrEAoW_hAeZ0NGiCs6umizKyLKCCc-489EHCAAQAVDkiO3_-f____8BYMOMroXIGKAB_o6g_APIAQGqBBlP0KYnVTXRplnR50WSK4QriilJmg24MTVf&sig=AOD64_2vF_TnF1xTdeWHIvg7DwLinbZ53g&adurl=http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn) and [SVN Tortoise](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=svn%20tortoise&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/&ei=H3XHTuK0GeH44QTv1dFJ&usg=AFQjCNE3AGLQNZb9GvR1WVhdQ8oQGhIG7Q&sig2=I2vOGE7fEIiHtRtT2ebsJw)